# Compute the limit: $\lim_{x\to e} (2-\ln x)^\frac{1}{x^2-e^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$L=\lim_{x\to e} (2-\ln x)^\frac{1}{x^2-e^2}$$

Here are my calculations:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to e} (2-\ln x)^\frac{1}{x^2-e^2}&=\lim_{x\to e} (1+1-\ln x)^\frac{1}{x^2-e^2}\\ &=\lim_{x\to e} ((1+1-\ln x)^\frac{1}{1-\ln x})^\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2-e^2}\\ &=e^{\lim_{x\to e}\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2-e^2}}.
\end{align}
Then, for the exponent,
$$
\lim_{x\to e} \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2-e^2}=\lim_{x\to e} \frac{\ln e-\ln x}{e^{2\ln x}-e^{2\ln e}}=\lim_{x\to e} \frac{\ln e-\ln x}{e^{2\ln e}(e^{2\ln x-2\ln e}-1)}=\frac{1}{e^2}\lim_{x\to e}\frac{\ln x- \ln e}{e^{2\ln x-2\ln e}-1}\frac{2\ln x-2 \ln e}{2\ln x-2 \ln e}=\frac{1}{e^2}\lim_{x\to e}\frac{-(\ln x-\ln e)}{2(\ln x-\ln e)}=-\frac{1}{2e^2}
$$
$$L=e^{-\frac{1}{2e^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[2e^2]{e}}$$

That's how I think this limit should be solved but my teacher got a different result.. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your teacher's result?

Comment: I don't remeber, he solved it on a pice of paper in seconds

Comment: @Dave: I improved much of your formatting, but you should ensure it is what you want, please.

Comment: Yeah, it s fine

Comment: According to Maple, your answer is right.

Comment: @BernardMassé what's Maple

Comment: It's possible that your teacher's answer is equivalent to this one. Without recalling or having written down exactly what your teacher had said, all we can tell you is that your solution is correct, even according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+goes+to+e+(2-ln(x))%5E(1%2F(x%5E2-e%5E2))).

Comment: Maple is similar to WolframAlpha (loosely said, but it gives you an idea).

Comment: @Clayton can you give me a link to Maple please?  I get multiple sites with this name

Comment: You answer is ok, you can also follow this route: $$\displaystyle L=\lim_{x\to e} (2-\ln x)^\dfrac{1}{x^2-e^2}=\lim_{x\to e} \bigg({(2-\ln x)^\dfrac{1}{x-e}}\bigg )^\dfrac{1}{x+e}=\bigg(\lim_{x\to e} {(1+(1-\ln x))^\dfrac{1}{x-e}}\bigg )^{\dfrac{1}{2e}}$$

Comment: [Here](https://www.maplesoft.com/) is a link. I don't use it, so I'm not sure it's the best possible link.

Comment: @Dave Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct indeed let $y=x-e \to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to e} (2-\ln x)^\frac{1}{x^2-e^2}=\lim_{y\to 0} (2-\ln (y+e))^\frac{1}{y(y+2e)}$$

and

$$(2-\ln (y+e))^\frac{1}{ y(y+2e) }=[(1+( 1-\ln(y+e) )^{\frac1{1-\ln(y+e)}}]^{\frac{1-\ln(y+e)}{y(y+2e)}}\to e^{-\frac1{2e^2}}$$

indeed

$$\frac{1-\ln(y+e)}{y(y+2e)}=\frac{1-\ln e-\ln(1+y/e)}{y(y+2e)}=-\frac1e \frac{\ln(1+y/e)}{y/e}\frac{1}{(y+2e)}\to -\frac1{2e^2}$$